# I'm stuck with this FreeCodeCamp algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    var toFilter;
    var toFrom;
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i]=="object") {
            toFilter = arguments[i];
        } else {
            toFrom = arguments[i];
        }
    }

    var result = toFilter.filter(function(value,index,array) {

        if(value===toFrom) {
            return true;
        }

        return result;

    });

    console.log(result);

}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // it should return [1,1]
```

It's almost been more than one week that i'm trying to solve this algorithm. In this task we need to remove the arguments value present in the initial array, they have mentioned to solve this by using arguments and filter method. Well i know what filter and arguments does in Javascript and i solved the previous algorithm using filter method and i read about arguments and it's use but never used it before. Every time i did something using these two it gave me a blank array. Please can anyone help me how can we do this using filter and arguments ?

Comment: Show your attempts that didn't work.

Comment: `it should return [1,1]` - why? what is the logic for returning two ones in an array? the comment for destroyer says "remove all the values" ... destroyer should return an empty array, one would think

Comment: put code attempts **in the question**

Comment: Yeah you can check the code attempt now@JaromandaX @Michael liu

Comment: still no explanation of how the output relates to the input - given that you say your code doesn't work, then the logic is still  undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just my idea, you can modify it the way you want:

```
function isValid() {
  return value != 2 && value != 3;
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
arr.filter(isValid); //It should return [1,1];
```

What you need now is to get 2 and 3 value from `arguments` object and change isValid function.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is construct a lookup of the values that you want to remove from the array, and then filter the original array by returning values that do not exist in the lookup:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var lookup = {};

  // For each remaining argument, add it to the lookup.
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    lookup[arguments[i]] = true;
  }

  // Filter the array and return a new array
  // with elements that don't exist in the lookup.
  return arr.filter(function(elem) {
    return typeof lookup[elem] === 'undefined';
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)); //it should return [1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems, let's list them one by one:

1. You overwrite `toFrom`, so instead of your intention to get ALL non-objects (i.e. 2 & 3), you only get the last non-object (i.e. 3)
2. In `filter()`, return `true` means **"Keep this element in the list"**, and you return `true` if the value is equal to `toFrom = 3`
3. The verb *solve* does not work with the noun *algorithm*.  Because *algorithm* is the way to *solve* a *problem*

---

I didn't try but I guess your code will output `[3,3]`, so if you want to output `[1,1]`, try following modified code based on your version:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    var toFilter;
    var toFrom = [];
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i]=="object") {
            toFilter = arguments[i];
        } else {
            // maintain a list of ALL non-objects which to be filtered
            toFrom.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }

    var result = toFilter.filter(function(value,index,array) {
        if(toFrom.indexOf(value) != -1) {
            // If element is in the toFrom list, DO NOT keep it
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

    console.log(result);

}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // it should return
```

or you may try my version :)

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
           arr = arr.filter( x => x !== arguments[i]);     
    }  
    console.log(arr);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); // it should return
```